# Lazy Regex Match in .NET. What's wrong here?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

In the following example I would like to retrieve the text *between* pMAINp and the *first* pMDSp. The regex has a look-behind and a look-ahead:

```
string contents = "pMAINp MAP B FlightTest Load pMDSp ZutiCarrier pWingp some pMDSp more pWingp end";
string blockMainRegex = @"(?<=pMAINp)[\s\w+]+(?=(pMDS)?)";
```

The result I was hoping for was:
" MAP B FlightTest Load "

but what it returns is:
"MAP B FlightTest Load pMDSp ZutiCarrier pWingp some pMDSp more pWingp end"

You'll notice that I'm attempting a lazy match here: (pMDS)? which clearly isn't working! 
Any help with this would be much appreciated. Thanks. :-)

**EDIT**: Whoops, the sought text has been corrected.

This works great:
    string blockMainRegex = @"(?<=pMAINp)[\s\w+]+?(?=pMDS)";

Comment: +1 - Just the question I needed answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You'll notice that I'm attempting a lazy match here: (pMDS)? which clearly isn't working!

You seem to be misunderstanding how lazy-matching works.

You apply the lazy operator to a *quantifier* - *, +, ? etc. - anywhere else, it's interpreted as "zero-or-one".

If you want one part of the regex to match as few characters as possible, apply the lazy operator to *the quantifier associated with that part of the regex* - in this case, you want to use it like so:

```
[\s\w+]+?
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string blockMainRegex = @"pMAINp(.*?)pMDSp";
```

The first group will have what you want.  E.g.:

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"pMAINp(.*?)pMDSp");
string result = re.Match(contents).Groups[1].ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks, actually I made a mistake with the sought text. Not corrected.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. You = top guy.